# I want to implement a tagging system on my news website

Tags: tags, web, tagging

I want to implement a tagging system on my news website. I do have two tables one is news and other is tags. in the news table, there are over 5000 news articles and in tags there are over 1000 tags: keywords relevant to each article.

Now I want to tag these tags (keywords) to the respective articles like many news websites like `NDTV.com`, the Hindu, and many others have. Each tag should have a link. When clicked, all the article tags with that particular tag, should be displayed.

How might I approach this task?